# Drag and Drop not working, if application lies in specific directory

Tags: windows, qt, drag-and-drop, qt5

I implemented a drag and drop functionality in an Qt application (In case you want to see some code, see below). I thought everything is working fine until a user told me that it is not working for him.

Usually you see this [image: Drag and drop ok] icon, if `dragEnterEvent()` does not call `event->acceptProposedAction()`, then you see this [image: Filetype unsupported] icon. And if the issue occurs you see an icon similar to this [image: Does not work icon] (It's not exactly that icon, but I am not able to capture it, as windows removes the mouse icon in screenshots).

We could find out that on some computers (not for me sadly, so debugging that is quite hard) it depends on the setup. In particular the installation path: If the application lies in one specific directory (or one of its subdirectories) the described error occurs. If we move the whole application directory somewhere else and execute it from there, everything works fine.

Adding some debug output showed that the dragEnterEvent() does not fire in the broken setup.

What could be the reason? How can I debug that issue?

---

We had some suspicions but nothing that realy makes sense. But I want to share them anyway:

- Permissions (But why should drag and drop rely on permissions, right?)
- Wrong libraries used (as there are multiple Qt versions installed)
- Another widget receives the event (How can that depend on the application directory?)

---

Code snippet:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent),
     /* more here */
{
    /* more here */
    setAcceptDrops(true);
    /* more here */
}

void MainWindow::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent* event)
{
    const QMimeData* mimeData = event->mimeData();

    if (mimeData->hasUrls()) {
        QString fileName = mimeData->urls().at(0).toLocalFile();
        QFileInfo file(fileName);

        if(isSupportedFileType(file.completeSuffix())) {
            event->acceptProposedAction();
        }
    }
}


void MainWindow::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    const QMimeData* mimeData = event->mimeData();

    if (mimeData->hasUrls()) {
        QList<QUrl> urlList = mimeData->urls();

        if(openFiles(urlList)) {
            event->acceptProposedAction();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one scenario where D+D seems to fail for no discernible reason.  Easy to repro on your machine, right-click the shortcut for your app and select "Run as Administrator".

[UIPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Interface_Privilege_Isolation) forbids dragging from a non-elevated app into an elevated one.  No loud feedback, your app simply doesn't get any of the D+D events.  Interview your user about this, you'll want to know if he has a need to elevate your app.  Having your installer automatically start your app will misbehave the same way.

Comment: This is something I already have thought about and in fact this might realy be possible as the directory it is not working in has a special setup. This are all company computers administrated centrally and that special directory seems to elevate the applications somehow. This is maybe more of a superuser question but do you know a way to see the privilege level of the application? The task manager shows nothing special.

Comment: Trying to reproduce like you said did not lead to the same result. But I think I just don't have the permission to do so. I think although I am klicking "Run as Administrator" Windows starts it with my users permissions.

Comment: You have to add the "Elevated" column in Task Manager's Details view to see it.  Or use SysInternals' Process Explorer.  Ask IT staff to help you out with this.

Comment: Well, for me it states "Not allowed". But it's working on my computer anyway. So I'll try it on a computer it's not working on and then report back. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: I could get some information regarding the elevation on a computer it is not working on. On that pc the field "UAC virtualization" is empty. Is that an indication, that your assumption is correct?

Comment: Too bad, that you are not answering anymore. But your answer was a help anyway, so I think you earned your bounty. Thank you for your help.